# Are the various Python Authorities (pypa, pycqa, etc.) somehow 'official'?

Tags: python

There are a few projects out there that use the moniker `Python ___ Authority` and the `py_a` abbreviation.

Examples are:

- The [Python Packaging Authority "pypa"](https://github.com/pypa)
- The [Python Code Quality Authority "pycqa"](https://github.com/PyCQA)
- The [Python Cryptographic Authority "pyca"](https://github.com/pyca)

These groups offer high-quality code and typically share developers among themselves and with the python core team.

I'm just wondering: are these groups licenced or official in some way? For example, does the [PSF](https://www.python.org/psf/) administer / approve them?

Comment: As for "does the PSF administer / approve them?", I do not think so. If they did we would have heard about it from their [blog](http://pyfound.blogspot.com/) or somewhere else and as far I know there were no such posts. By the way, Pylint (which is now under PCQA) is not 100% accurate if it comes to PEP hance I do not think that they are real 'authorities'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Speaking as one of the members of the PyCA, no, there is no official licensing body and we are not licensed.

The Python Packaging Authority was originally started by the team that worked on `pip`. Today the PyPA administers essentially all of the packaging infrastructure for Python making it the de facto authority.

The Python Cryptographic Authority aspires to be the primary resource for Python developers needing cryptographic libraries, but our authority is derived solely from developer opinion of the quality of our software.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. But curiosity got the better of me so I had to ask, and googling didn't find anything. :-)

Answer (score 9):

PyCA is just some people hanging out, making computer programs. We're not "official", for any definition thereof.